# verify operations through email

Tags: users, emails, commerce

I need to ensure that the user is the one who is acting on the website by sending hash code generated to his emial or sms message before complete an operation.

we have implemented account balance so we need to prevent others use his balance by verify the account owner.

### Scenario wanted to achieve:

```
User add items to his cart
Send hash code to his email 
verify the code 
Complete to checkout
```

What is the best practice to achieve?

[using commerce framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) -- [commerce account balance](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_account_balance)

Comment: `I need to ensure that the user is the one who is acting on the website` Why not use a Captcha?

Comment: we need to ensure the user pay as we have account balance not to ensure human or robot

Comment: `we have implemented account balance so we need to prevent others use his balance` **Isn't it safe to assume that if the user logged in that it is him?**

Comment: @No Sssweat You are totally right and there exist many other solutions but you know clients have their own mind and way of thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force user registration before checkout and allow Drupal to handle this. There are a couple of things you can do to make it very tough for non-humans to get through:

1. Require user verification for registration. This is out of the box functionality with Drupal and is accessible in the system configuration area.
2. Consider using a module such as [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) or [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) to expose traps for bots so that they cannot continue.

Don't work against Drupal's user and form system on this one. Let them do the work for you.

Comment: You are totally right and I argued the client for that point, But the client insisted !!

Comment: IMO, you ought to insist in the proper way of doing things. The last thing you want is to build a system that ends up having some vulnerability that allows a 3rd party to spend from another person's account.